# wordpress slider that works on wordpress text widget

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel, text-widget

I need your help.
Is there any wordpress slider that works on text widget.

I used owl carousel, but it didn't work for me it shows me a empty div

```html
<section id="presentation">
<h1>PRESENTATION</h1>
<p>Avada has the ability for you to make a one page site with a parallax scrolling menu</p>
<hr>
 <div class="one-third first">
   <div class="slider-container">
   <h4>VIDEO PRESENTATION</h4>
[owl-carousel category="mainSlider"]
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="two-thirds">

 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LdjTQif9s4M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

 </div>
</section>
```

but it shows me this line of code

```html
<div id="owl-carousel-1488532950" class="owl-carousel" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
```

thanks everyone.

Comment: You can change "text widget" to "PHP widget" in PHP widget use  echo do_shortcode('[owl-carousel category="mainSlider"]');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php text widget and directly use php code

Answer (score 0):

You can change "text widget" to "PHP widget" in PHP widget use

```
 echo do_shortcode('[owl-carousel category="mainSlider"]');
```